# Resharper if Unit Test Fails Always Run Specific Code

Tags: c#, com, resharper, mstest

This may or may not be the correct way to do it. I am running unit tests that create an object via COM and runs some tests on the object. I have set the tests thus far to use:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void Setup()
{
    // Code to create object
}

[TestMethod()]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    // Run the tests on object
}

[ClassCleanup]
public static void UnSetup()
{
    // Dispose of object
}
```

The problem is sometimes while I am debugging or some other unit test fails, the UnSetup() function does not run because the unit tests end prematurely. This leaves me with an object that should have been deleted, thus throwing in error in the unit test. What is the best way to tackle this?

p.s. Other tests also use the object which is why I use [ClassCleanup] not [TestCleanup]

Comment: Where does the error get thrown?

Comment: If I run the tests again it throws an error inside of the [TestMethod()]. It does this because it asserts that the GUID of the item matches the created item...problem is that the item already exists so it's creating two of the same item and comparing the GUIDS of the duplicate thus throwing an error.

Comment: In the meantime I found a work around, I definitely do not think of it as a solution: inside of  the [ClassInitialize] I do this : var itm = GetItem() ?? NewItem();

Comment: The workaround sounds perfectly valid, especially if you cannot guarantee  the test will clean up nicely. Other option is to move to nUnit for testing instead of MSTest.

Comment: I guess that was what I was really looking for. I couldn't find validation on the "proper way" to do it. Thank you by the way

Comment: When dealing with COM and the quirks of a testing framework, the "proper way" is whatever gets the tests running. De nada.

Comment: @dbugger Could you actually put the comment I upvoted as the answer so I can mark it as the answer for my question? Thanks man.

Comment: It's not answer worthy.